# EF Core sum date with timespan inside where statement

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

In EF Core 3.1, I have the following model

```
 public class Advertisement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EndPeriod { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; } 
}
```

I have a simple requirement to check if an advertisement end period is less than the current date plus the duration using LINQ.

**I've tried**

```
ads.Where(a => EF.Functions
               .DateDiffMinute(a.EndPeriod, DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(a.Duration)) <= 0)
```

but throws an error saying :

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation.

is there any way to fix this without client-side evaluation?

Comment: Isn't that an EF core 5.0 feature ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this expression `DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(a.Duration)` cannot be translated.

Try to use something like:

```
ads
  .Select(a => new
  {
     ...
     a.EndPeriod,
     Period = DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(a.Duration)
  })
  .Where(a => EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(a.EndPeriod, a.Period) <= 0)
```

Comment: I was writing the same approach. Removing my answer since we both answered the same way.

Comment: If `DateTimeOffset.Now.Add(a.Duration)` cannot be translated, how putting it into intermediate projection helps? It still can't be translated.